# Not opening the App when clicking the brach.io link instead going to the playstore

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I configured my app for deep linking as mentioned in Branch.io documentation. Below is my Configuration

Manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="trupik" android:host="open" />
                <data android:scheme="trupik" android:host="https" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="trupikconnect.app.link" android:pathPrefix="/x2ms"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="trupik.com" android:pathPrefix="/x2ms"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

In Welcome Activity which is my Launcher Activity

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked before showing up
                    Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.setIntent(intent);
    }
```

My url Scheme in branch dashboard is trupik://
Note: Package name is also same.

My problem is when I click the link App is not being opened even though it is Installed

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: looks like your Activity definition has a couple of errors in it. Try this instead, and let me know if you're still having trouble!

```
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true">
    <data android:scheme="trupik" android:host="open" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="trupikconnect.app.link" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```